# bootbox.js -> Show button in bootbox.dialog() only if condition is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I use bootbox to create a dialog, but I want certain buttons only to show up under certain conditions.

I searched a lot, but found nothing helpful..

I define the bootbox like this:

```
bootbox.dialog({
   title: "title",
   message: "text",
   buttons: {
      btn1: {
         label: "Button 1",
         callback: function () {
            /* do something */                                
         }
      },
      btn2: {
         label: "Button 2",
         callback: function () {
            /* do something */                                
         }
      }       
});
```

How can I make the second Button only appear `if(condition == true)` ?

I also tried to remove the button afterwards like this:

```
bootbox.dialog({...})
if(!condition) {
   $('[data-bb-handler="btn2"]').remove();
}
```

But with no success.

Any idea appreciated!

Greetz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just modify the buttons object that you pass to your bootbox, like so

```
  var buttons = {
    btn1: {
      label: "Button 1",
      callback: function() {
        /* do something */
      }
    },
  }

  // change here !!!    
  if (false)
    buttons.btn2 = {
      label: "Button 2",
      callback: function() {
        /* do something */
      }
    }

  bootbox.dialog({
    title: "title",
    message: "text",
    buttons: buttons
  });
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/7x5h91v2/

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `className` in bootbox like this :

```
var condition = false;
var displayButton="show";
if(condition){
    displayButton="hide";
}

var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
    title: "title",
    message: "text",
    buttons: {
        btn1: {
            label: "Button 1",
            callback: function() {
                /* do something */
            }
        },
        btn2: {
            className: displayButton,
            label: "Button 2",
            callback: function() {
                /* do something */
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Working exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/py6wbmvp/

Comment: Thanks Quentin, interesting approach. But i prefer #potatos answer, because the buttons aren't generated at all, not only hidden. Also it is a bit more flexible